# Get product attributes from Order

Tags: magento-2.1, php, orders, product-attribute

I need to get product attributes for product items in Order. How can I do this?
I got order details per one order from below line of code and I used loop to cycle through every order.

```
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
```

I need to get certain attribute value from each item in the order. I tried *getAllvisibleitems* as follows,

```
$items =$orderObj->getAllVisibleItems();
```

but it doesn't include data for the attributes. For example I need to get value from attribute ***manufacturer***,

How can I get manufacturer of each item in the order?

Comment: Can somebody help me out please?

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to get all product attributes by

```
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
$orderAllItems = $orderObj->getAllItems();
if ($orderAllItems) {
    foreach ($orderAllItems as $item) {
        $customatt = $item->getProduct()->getCustomAtt();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: tested in Magento 2.3

Comment: This works for me. The absence of the "getProduct()" was what was preventing this from getting the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get product attribute for product items in Order.

```
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
$orderAllItems = $orderObj->getAllItems();
if ($orderAllItems) {
    foreach ($orderAllItems as $item) {
        $product_manufacturer = $item->getManufacturer();
    }
}
```

You can get all attribute from `$item`.

Comment: Few problems actually. I tried above and when I try this, it throws a fatal error saying area code is not set. And also I need to get only one attribute at once. I just need the attribute value for certain single item each

Comment: Check again. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but still, I've problems. it wont show anything now. **manufacturer** is a custom attribute, I might add that

Comment: Please add screenshot, which error occurred?

Comment: No error shown, just nothing gets printed. I tried **print_r($item->getData());** and it shows bunch of data about the product but nothing on attributes. I tried **print_r($item->getManufacturer());** and it shows nothing

Comment: Hi are you there?