# How to get ordered product CGST, SGST & IGST from order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, tax

[image]

how to get this amount?
I try -

```
foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
$productId = $item->getProductId();
$productName = $item->getName();
$productSku = $item->getSku();
$Price = $item->getPrice();
$qtyOrdered = intval($item->getQtyOrdered());
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221204/get-product-attributes-from-order?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
public $priceHelper;

\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceHelper

$this->priceHelper  = $priceHelper;

foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $CgstCharge = $this->priceHelper->currency($item->getCgstCharge(),true,false);
    $SgstCharge = $this->priceHelper->currency($item->getSgstCharge(),true,false);
    $IgstCharge = $this->priceHelper->currency($item->getIgstCharge(),true,false);
}
```